# Is There a Way to Refresh a Chrome Browser on Widows from an External Program?

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext2

I'd like to know if there is some kind of program that reloads Chrome that I could call externally (from another program).

I'm using SublimeText and I want to call a refresh on my active Chrome browser (s) when I click on ctrl+S. I know how to call a system command or a batch file from SublimeText, but the part I'm missing is the one where the browser is refreshed automatically.

The ideal would be a .exe that I could call from command line (or a batch file or whatever).

I'm on Windows.

P.S. I don't want to install an extension that refresh the browser automatically when the css changes, for example (our system is more complicated than just static HTML and CSS).

And I don't want to put some "hacks" inside my HTML to refresh the page each X seconds.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) for Mac and Win users.  And [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) for linux.